# Padrino with mysql, rake fails

Tags: ruby, sinatra, padrino

I just wanna give a try on the new frame Padrino. I followed the steps given [here](http://www.padrinorb.com/guides/blog-tutorial).
I am stuck at running the rake tasks. 
I used Mysql as my database. I created the project using the command.
**padrino g project sample_blog -t shoulda -e haml -c sass -s jquery -d activerecord -a mysql  padrino g admin**

I have all the dependencies in order, I did **Bundle install** to ensure it.
Then when I run the rake task I get this error.

**$ padrino rake ar:create --trace**  
=> Executing Rake ar:create --trace ...
** Invoke ar:create (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute ar:create
rake aborted!
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/padrino-gen-0.9.14/lib/padrino-gen/padrino-tasks/activerecord.rb:56:in`create_database'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/padrino-gen-0.9.14/lib/padrino-gen/padrino-tasks/activerecord.rb:31
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:636:in `call'

/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:636:in`execute'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:631:in `each'

/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:631:in`execute'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:597:in `invoke_with_call_chain'

/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in`synchronize'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:590:in `invoke_with_call_chain'

/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:583:in`invoke'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2051:in `invoke_task'

/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in`top_level'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `each'

/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in`top_level'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exception_handling'

/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2023:in`top_level'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/padrino-core-0.9.14/lib/padrino-core/cli/rake.rb:9:in `init'

/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/padrino-core-0.9.14/lib/padrino-core/cli/base.rb:50:in`rake'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/thor-0.13.4/lib/thor/task.rb:33:in `send'

/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/thor-0.13.4/lib/thor/task.rb:33:in`run'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/thor-0.13.4/lib/thor/invocation.rb:109:in `invoke'

/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/thor-0.13.4/lib/thor/invocation.rb:116:in`call'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/thor-0.13.4/lib/thor/invocation.rb:116:in `invoke'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/thor-0.13.4/lib/thor.rb:137:in`start'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/thor-0.13.4/lib/thor/base.rb:378:in `start'

/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/thor-0.13.4/lib/thor.rb:124:in`start'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/padrino-core-0.9.14/bin/padrino:24
/usr/bin/padrino:19:in `load'
/usr/bin/padrino:19

**$ padrino rake ar:migrate --trace**
=> Executing Rake ar:migrate --trace ...
** Invoke ar:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute ar:migrate
rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished
/home/deepak/.bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/activerecord-  2.3.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:326:in `retrieve_connection'

/home/deepak/.bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/activerecord-  2.3.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:123:in`retrieve_connection'
/home/deepak/.bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/activerecord-  2.3.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:115:in `connection'

/home/deepak/.bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:440:in`initialize'
/home/deepak/.bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:401:in `new'

/home/deepak/.bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:401:in`up'
/home/deepak/.bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.8/lib/active_record/migration.rb:383:in `migrate'

/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/padrino-gen-0.9.14/lib/padrino-gen/padrino-tasks/activerecord.rb:136

/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:636:in`call'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:636:in `execute'

/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:631:in`each'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:631:in `execute'

/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:597:in`invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'

/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:590:in`invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:583:in `invoke'

/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2051:in`invoke_task'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `top_level'

/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in`each'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `top_level'

/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2068:in`standard_exception_handling'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2023:in `top_level'

/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/padrino-core-0.9.14/lib/padrino-core/cli/rake.rb:9:in`init'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/padrino-core-0.9.14/lib/padrino-core/cli/base.rb:50:in `rake'

/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/thor-0.13.4/lib/thor/task.rb:33:in`send'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/thor-0.13.4/lib/thor/task.rb:33:in `run'

/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/thor-0.13.4/lib/thor/invocation.rb:109:in`invoke'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/thor-0.13.4/lib/thor/invocation.rb:116:in `call'

/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/thor-0.13.4/lib/thor/invocation.rb:116:in`invoke'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/thor-0.13.4/lib/thor.rb:137:in `start'

/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/thor-0.13.4/lib/thor/base.rb:378:in`start'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/thor-0.13.4/lib/thor.rb:124:in `start'

/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/padrino-core-0.9.14/bin/padrino:24

/usr/bin/padrino:19:in`load'
/usr/bin/padrino:19

Comment: Might be a stupid question, but is your mysql server started? Is the connection information in the database.rb file correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished

Did you enter your MySQL username and password information into the database.rb?